# How to disable model/weight serialization fully with AllenNLP settings?

Tags: allennlp

I wish disable serializing all model/state weights in standard AllenNLP model training via the use of `jsonnet` config files.

The reason for this is that I am running automatic hyperparameter optimization using Optuna.
Testing dozens of models fills up a drive pretty quickly.
I already have disabled the checkpointer by setting `num_serialized_models_to_keep` to `0`:

```
trainer +: {
    checkpointer +: {
        num_serialized_models_to_keep: 0,
    },
```

I do not wish to set `serialization_dir` to `None` as I still want the default behaviour regarding logging of intermediate metrics, etc. I only want to **disable the default model state, training state, and best model weights writing**.

Besides the option I set above, are there any default trainer or checkpointer options to disable all serialization of model weights? I checked the API docs and webpage but could not find any.

If I need to define the functionality for such an option myself, which base function(s) from the AllenNLP should I override in my Model subclass?

Alternatively, is their any utility for cleaning up intermediate model state when training is concluded?

**EDIT:** [@petew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64323043/2425270) shows the solution for a custom checkpointer, but I am not clear on how to make this code findable to `allennlp train` for my use-case.

I wish to make the custom_checkpointer callable from a config file as below:

```
trainer +: {
    checkpointer +: {
        type: empty,
    },
```

What would be best practice to load the checkpointer when calling `allennlp train --include-package <$my_package>`?

I have my_package with submodules in subdirectories such as `my_package/models`s and `my_package/training`.
I would like to place the custom checkpointer code in `my_package/training/custom_checkpointer.py`
My main model is located in `my_package/models/main_model.py`.
Do I have to edit or import any code/functions in my main_model class to use the custom checkpointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create and register a custom [Checkpointer](https://docs.allennlp.org/master/api/training/checkpointer/) that basically just does nothing:

```
@Checkpointer.register("empty")
class EmptyCheckpointer(Registrable):
    def maybe_save_checkpoint(
        self, trainer: "allennlp.training.trainer.Trainer", epoch: int, batches_this_epoch: int
    ) -> None:
        pass

    def save_checkpoint(
        self,
        epoch: Union[int, str],
        trainer: "allennlp.training.trainer.Trainer",
        is_best_so_far: bool = False,
        save_model_only=False,
    ) -> None:
        pass

    def find_latest_checkpoint(self) -> Optional[Tuple[str, str]]:
        pass

    def restore_checkpoint(self) -> Tuple[Dict[str, Any], Dict[str, Any]]:
        return {}, {}

    def best_model_state(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will probably work, but I have no idea what the best practice is for AllenNLP to find this custom checkpointer.

See my edit in OP for more details on why I need clarification.

Comment: If your custom checkpointer is in `my_package/training/custom_checkpointer.py`, then you could call `allennlp train` with `--include-package my_package.training.custom_checkpointer`, or you could create a file called `.allennlp_plugins` in your repo and put "my_package.training.custom_checkpointer" on it's own line in that file.

Comment: Here's an example `.allennlp_plugins` file: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-template-config-files/blob/master/.allennlp_plugins